# ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'

Tags: python, pandas

I get this error when I try to open the CSV file (occupies 500Mb):

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
```

This is the code that I used to create the file that I now try to open. This code reads numerous files in the folder and merges them ina single pandas DataFrame. All of these files have the same number of columns, while different number of rows.

```
base_path = "C://Test"
path, dirs, files = next(os.walk(base_path))

df_main = pd.DataFrame
for f in files:
    file_path = base_path+"/"+f
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=";", index_col=False)
    if df_main.empty:
        df_main = df
    else:
        df_main = pd.concat([df_main, df], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I think this could have many sources, it's a catch-all. However, I found this same error when I had a file on Linux and the file termination was still using dos line breaks. Using the command dos2unix fixed the problem.

In general when I find issues like this on pandas file read I try to read the file using a standard file read and print to console.